# Why do I often see this Javascript construct/convention? (i.e. creating 'var foo;' on it's own line, instead of via assignment)

Tags: javascript

I often see Javascript programmers do something like this:

```
function(index, input) {
  var $input;
  $input = $(input);
  return $input.data('foo', 'bar');
}
```

While what I would have thought to do was something like this:

```
function(index, input) {
  var $input = $(input);
  return $input.data('foo', 'bar');
}
```

Or in this particular case, actually this:

```
function(index, input) {
  return $(input).data('foo', 'bar');
}
```

What is the value of declaring 'var' on a single line, then assigning to them later?  It seems to me that adding the extra lines only leads to possible problems (for example, someone could forget to add the 'var' and accidentally make global variables).  So why do it this way?

Is this just a coding convention of some kind (readability, maybe?), or is there some fiddly thing with how JavaScript works internally that makes this construct more efficient somehow?

Comment: @Jon Where is it used twice? It's only used once, in all three examples

Comment: @Ian see the first revision

Comment: @JanDvorak Of course, I need to start remembering to think of that; thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I had used the wrong example.  The current one is what I mean to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

int this simple example it makes no difference as much as i can say. but in javascript var declarations in a function body are evaluated first. so it makes a lot of sense to add all var declarations at the top of the function, also if they are only used later.

```
a = "GLOBAL";

function x(){
    console.log(a);
    var a = "VAR";
    console.log(a);
}

x()
```

will print

```
undefined
VAR
```

and not

```
GLOBAL
VAR
```

Comment: Yep, I always thought javascript scoping rules were a little weird.

Comment: @JoeEnos variables in javascript are function-scoped. Other than that, I love the scoping rules

Comment: Thanks, this is an actual non-sylistic reason and it makes sense.  Ah JavaScript, you so crayze!  :)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the value of declaring 'var' on a single line, then assigning to them later?

There is none. It makes no difference one way or the other. Simple as that.

Comment: Depends on what is ultimately meant by "later". Given the simple example in the question, there's no difference. Given a more complex example, some would suggest that it's a good practice to declare all variables at the top of the function to not be tricked by the "hoisting" behavior.

Comment: Well, yes. I interpreted the question as *"Is there a difference between declare, then assign or declare-and-assign?"*. And there's not.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a style thing.I'm partial to your second example as well, and often declare and assign multiple variables in the same statement. I can't think of any reason to do otherwise, and would argue that separating the two statements could just cause confusion later as your code grows.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I didn't know if maybe the JavaScript interpreter did something crazy, like maybe not garbage collecting objects when declaring them one way vs another, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a variable you need to keep in scope (or you're in strict mode) so you must declare your variables with `var`. However, you *might not use* that variable, depending on some condition. Consider:

```
var foo;
if(cond1) {
    foo = "something";
} else if(cond2) {
    foo = "something else";
} else if(cond3) {
    foo = "a third thing";
}
```

Without your opening `var foo`, you'll need to do:

```
if(cond1) {
    var foo = "something";
} else if(cond2) {
    var foo = "something else";
} else if(cond3) {
    var foo = "a third thing";
}
```

(This is primarily due out of maintenance concern -- you could get by with a single `var foo = ..` and let the rest be simply `foo = ...`, but as soon as you comment out or  alter that case, the behavior of `foo` will change.)

It doesn't look as nice, *and* you've unconditionally declared `foo` in this scope (since declarations are [hoisted to the top of the scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)). If this code were buried deep in some function, it might not be clear to a reader in the second case whether `foo` is declared or not.

Comment: This is slightly different. I understand why you'd need to do it in the case you mentioned, I just didn't see a use for it when you declare it and then use it one line later.